# What are some elegant ways to monitor a property via an attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, attributes

I have properties on classes that I want to cache the values of (their past values). The objects themselves will keep track of their changes but I want to be able to mark the properties I want to keep track of with a simple attribute. How can I monitor the changes on the properties without any manual code per property?

Comment: [Unity interception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) is an option - wrap all your instances and capture information before/after calls. Nothing to do with attributes, so not an answer... (I'm not completely sure what you mean "monitor via attribute" as attributes don't mean/do anything by themselves)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'd like to create a system that when a property is marked with an attribute, its changed are monitored automatically by some other subsystem.

Comment: You may want to add how you want code to look like in the answer - sample object and sample creation of an object... Also note if you already have something like `INotifyPropertyChanged` wired up.

Comment: Have you try INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306746/attach-an-event-to-a-property-when-changed

Comment: @user3277522 It's evil in that I have to use reflection to get values back... but I guess that can't be helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use generic proxy pattern.
There is a lot of proxy generator but you can use real/transparent proxy provided by remoting.

Intercept call to property and do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an attribute to extend or change the behavior of a property with something like monitoring,  caching, validation, or logging you might want to consider [AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming),  [a good white paper can be found here too](http://www.postsharp.net/white-papers/aop)

The most common AOP tool in .net is [Post Sharp](http://www.postsharp.net/).

with that library/tool integrated in your solution and visual studio, it will look for specific attributes that it recognizes as aspects and applies them at compile (or run time, depends on some factors) to the target property, method, class, or even an entire assembly.

with post sharp, a [location interception aspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/location-interception) would allow you to intercept execution of a target (before execution, after, or when an error occurs) and write some code to be executed when those interceptions happen, and you will be given metadata about the target being intercepted (PropertyInfo for example) and the instance of that object currently being intercepted, or errors that occurred.

There are some predefined aspects (attributes) that come packaged with post sharp and you can use them right away, or you can create your own aspects (attributes) with any different behavior.